# How do I execute a python command in maya from a python script

Tags: python-2.7, maya, mel

I'm having a bit of difficulty running a python command at the end of a function. Basically, I have a UI that takes curves and writes them to json files. At the end of my write_curve_to_file() function, I'm wanting to reload the UI to update the list of curves in the directory with the line control_manager.shapeTools_UI()
The problem I'm getting is that this is a python command and when it gets executed, maya is expecting a mel command and I get the error "Cannot find procedure". So what I'm wanting to do is either tell maya that I want to run this as a python command, or convert it to a mel command and use the mel.eval() function to execute it. The preference would be not needing to import the maya.mel module and to keep it to python.
Any help appreciated.
EDIT: A snippet from my code that is trying to reload the UI

```
    with open(ctrl_lib + "\\" + obj + ".json", "w") as json_file:
        json.dump(curve_dict, json_file)
    cmds.confirmDialog(
        title='Result',
        message='Save successful',
        button=['OK'],
        defaultButton='OK',
        cancelButton='OK',
        dismissString='OK')
    control_manager.shapeTools_UI()
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? Maya does not need mel code to execute UI functions, it can take python functions, so I suppose something in your UI design can be improved.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the code that is trying to execute the UI. The UI code isn't the problem, that works fine, it's just trying to get it to reload after the confirm dialog that is causing me a problem.

Comment: Coming back to this today, it seems to work without any error. So I'm guessing it was nothing wrong with the scripts after all. Perhaps it just needed a maya restart and the modules reloading.